# Laravel 4, Ubuntu, Apache upload file in a folder with me as owner

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, laravel-4

I am using Laravel 4. My operating system is Ubuntu 13.10 and my local server is Apache.
What I am trying to do is upload a file to the server under a folder. The problem is that both the folder and the file after the upload are owned by 'nobody' while I want me to be the owner and have all the permissions too. I don t want a solution such as cmod or chown on terminal cause both of them need to be executed every time I upload a file. Even if a change the owner of the folder uploads the files are not correctly uploaded.Here is my form(firstform.blade.php):

```
<form action="{{ url('form-handler') }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" />

<input  name="foo"  /><br/>
<input  name="baz"  />
<br/>

<input type="file" name="book" />
<input type="submit" value="Send" />


</form>
```

And here is my routes:

```
Route::get('firstform', function()
{
    return View::make('firstform');


});


Route::post('form-handler',function(){

$name = Input::file('book')->getClientOriginalName();

$path=Input::file('book')->move('uploads/', $name);

echo 'The file uploaded is : ' .$name .' and is located in ' .$path ;


});
```

Comment: You can use chgrp() in PHP http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.chgrp.php

Comment: Do you know how to employ that in laravel..?

Comment: This isn't a Laravel problem, although you could solve it through Laravel.  What you should really do is make sure your web server, or at least your PHP CGI, is running under the user you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the user under which the Apache server is operating - to the same user as yours. That makes the files/folders created by Apache owned by the proper user (you) so they are accessible.

To switch the Apache user in Ubuntu you have to:

Edit the envvars file:

```
sudo gedit /etc/apache2/envvars
```

Change:

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=nobody
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=nobody
```

to:

```
#export APACHE_RUN_USER=nobody
#export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=nobody
export APACHE_RUN_USER=YOUR_USER_NAME
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=YOUR_USER_NAME
```

Comment: This may not be ideal for a live environment, though. The Apache user runs as a separate user for a reason - it helps limit the damage if a cracker gets past security defences.

Answer (score 0):

firstly you should create root folder in which you are suppose to upload file into it change group of that root dir..

```
chgrp dirname  groupname
```

and make  www-data apache user member of that group
  then you will be able to access that file..

Comment: It didn t work for me..I maybe wrong on how I add the user..Is tis correct sudo useradd -g john_90  www-data ..?

Comment: Actually I just give an idea you need to explore